# How does the sun rise upwards with brightening and set downwards with low fading being stationary on a spinning earth?

Tags: visible-light, sun

Can someone please apprise me with this phenomena that earth is spinning on it's own axis with 23.5 degrees tilt also rotating around the sun while sun is stationary. when sun is just rising up we can easily see the sun with no harming light affect *(like yolk)* similarly during sun set. 
How is sun light being brighter and fade ? if earth is spinning 23.5 degrees *whatever direction* how does sun go up during rise and go down during set with increasing and decreasing light ?

my question is *(about moving direction)*. if sun is stationary not moving. why we see that it's going high during sun rise and going down during sun set from each region. in June why we see sun path changed as it comes above to my head if earth was spinning in same direction it's path should not be changed.

Other thing is *(about more and less brightening)* during a sun rise/set we can see sun easily without any harm of light to eyes. what thing makes this change, how sun becomes more brighter during rising and faded during sun set?
please enlighten.

Comment: At low sun angles the sun must penetrate far more of the earth's atmosphere.  Hence the apparent brightness of the sun is reduced by the increased absorption and diffusion of light as it passes through the atmosphere.

Comment: Are you asking about the phenomenon of sunrise and sunset (just hold a ball in front of a light and spin it slowly), or about the changing brightness of the sun as a function of angle above the horizon? For the latter, see for example [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/129494/26969)