# How much air would be needed to block sunlight?

Tags: optics, visible-light, atmospheric-science, air, absorption

Was watching a sunset on the sea, I was wondering what would be a lower bound for the thickness of air needed to almost completely obscure the reddish light of the sun, or at least to make it impossible to distinguish the sun's shape. I was not able to wrap my head around google results when it comes to optical properties of air, so I'm at a loss.

Let's assume red light with a wavelength of around 650 nanometers, dry air at 1 bar of pressure, temperature of 20° celsius.

Comment: What google results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest contributor to a "red sunset" is scattering from small particles; I wrote an [earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/129494/26969) about that. But I am assuming that you want the answer for "clean, dry air" (although you only specified "dry", I think the two go together). I am going to have to make a lot of assumptions, so the answer will be quite approximate.

Starting with the data given in ["UV, Visible and IR attenuation for Altitudes to 50 km"](http://dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=AD0671933), we see that they posit that in the absence of particles the predominant loss mechanism is Rayleigh scattering off the molecules. They then explain that the refractive index is a good proxy for Rayleigh scattering cross section, and proceed to derive an expression for the attenuation that this generates. After about 20 pages of measurements of aerosol concentrations (which, as I said before, tend to dominate the mean free path of light in the atmosphere), we get to a large set of tables. The answer to your question is in table 4.13, part of which I reproduce here:

[image]

The number of interest is $5.893\times 10^{-3} ~\rm{/km}$ - the "Rayleigh attenuation coefficient at sea level for 0.65 micron light."

Now the eye is pretty good at making out the shape of a circle in the presence of background haze - let's assume that your criterion is met when you have reach 99% attenuation (1% of sunlight still going, 99% scattered into $4\pi$. Then the thickness of the layer of clean dry air at atmospheric pressure that you would need is computed from

$$0.01 = e^{-\mu t}\\
-\mu t = \log{0.01}\\
t = \frac{\log{100}}{\mu}$$

When $\mu = 5.893\times 10^{-3}$ km, the **thickness of air needed is about 800 km**