# Color of sun during sunset on moon

Tags: visible-light, sun

I just learned that sunset on earth is orange because of the *Rayleigh Scattering* effect. The dust particles in the atmosphere scatters the sunlight during the sunset.

However, since the **moon has no atmosphere**, does that mean the sun looks white even during sunset? I couldn't any pictures/articles on this online.

Comment: Vaguely related: [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/129494/26969)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. Due to the lack of substantial atmosphere on the moon there would not be the color effect that you see here on the Earth. In fact the sun would appear the same during its entire transit. Since you asked for an article this has a nice video sim of what it would look like from the [Kurdistan Planetarium in the U.K](http://earthsky.org/space/how-often-can-you-see-sunrises-and-sunsets-from-the-moon).